# Do the eigenstates of the Pauli operators correspond to the six directions of the 3D world?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, measurement-problem, spinors, bloch-sphere

I understand that the six eigenstates of the three Pauli operators $X, Y, Z$ correspond to the six poles of the Bloch sphere. By fixing an orthonormal basis of our physical word, does "*measuring Pauli operator $X$*" actually mean measuring the spin of a particle in the direction $x$ (of the "real world")? If this is the case, then the measurement in the respective basis makes perfect "real" sense.

Comment: What do you mean *"by perfect real sense"*?

Comment: The Pauli basis for "real" spins is always relative to some coordinate system "in the real world". For other two-level systems (e.g. two levels in an atom), this is not so clear.

Comment: @gonenc If this sentence is not very clear, please ignore it.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch So the answer is positive at least for "real" spins?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but I would say "yes".  Note, however, that these "real world" coordinate systems can be aligned in any way you want.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Yes, the coordinates systems can be chosen freely and thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Let's look at a spin measurement in detail.

You can choose any direction $\hat n = n_x\hat x+n_y\hat y+n_z\hat z$ and take any spin, $ \alpha |+\rangle+\beta |-\rangle,$ where we define $|\pm\rangle$ by $$\left(n_x\sigma_x+n_y\sigma_y+n_z\sigma_z\right) |\pm\rangle=\pm|\pm\rangle).$$

Then you can send a beam of particles into a small region with an inhomogeneous magnetic field in direction $\hat n$ and with the beam coming in orthogonal to $\hat n.$ The Schrödinger equation predicts that the beam evolves into two separated beam and that the spin vector evolves to align itself so that in one beam the spin is $|+\rangle$ and in the other beam the spin is $|-\rangle.$

If you look at the two separated beams you can track the probability current backwards, note that these streamlines never cross and that it is the streamlines that had larger values of $\vec r \cdot \hat n$ that ended up in the $+\hat n$ deflected beam that ends with spin $|+\rangle$ and that it was streamlines that had smaller values of $\vec r \cdot \hat n$ that ended up in the $-\hat n$ deflected beam that ends with spin $|-\rangle$ (where smaller means more negative and larger means more positive).

The exact dividing plane between the streamlines that go $+\hat n$ and the streamlines that go $-\hat n$ ends up being where the ratio of the L2 norm of the upwards deflected beam over the L2 norm of the downwards deflected beam equals $|\alpha/\beta|^2.$

And all of that comes just from a detailed and realistic Hamiltonian for the actual experimental setup. No collapse or special rules, just a realistic model of the actual experimental setup and how it evolves.

So now that we have an accurate and detailed model of a spin measurement, let's look at your question.

What does it mean to measure the Pauli operator $\sigma_x$?  It means we send a beam moving in a direction orthogonal to x into a region with an external magnetic field that points in the $\hat x$ direction and is inhomogeneous and based on the strength of the field (and its inhomogeneity) we get some deflect in the $\pm \hat x$ that over enough space fully separated the beams and in each beam aligns the spin in that beam to be an eigenvectors of $\sigma_x.$ And the size of the two beams is determined by the relative size of the projection of the incoming spin onto the eigenspaces of $\sigma_x.$

There is nothing special about $\sigma_x$ it just happens to correspond to $\hat n=\hat x$ and any $\hat n$ works just as well.

But you aren't revealing a preexisting spin, you are forcing the spin state to go into spin eigenstates while you are deflecting beams.

How do we know you aren't revealing a preexisting spin?  Note that there are two ways to measure the x component of spin, you can take a magnetic field with an inhomogeneity in the $+\hat x$ direction and look for $+\hbar/2$ as the "x component of spin" in the upward ($+\hat x$) deflected beam.

But an equally good way is to use a device with reversed polarity in the inhomogeneous magnetic field so every place has an exact opposite magnetic field.  In this device the spin of $+\hbar/2$ as the "x component of spin" is in the downward ($-\hat x$) deflected beam.

There is absolutely nothing wrong with this new device it measured spins in exactly the same way, it deflects a pure spin $+\hbar/2$ one way and a pure spin $-\hbar/2$ an opposite way and the relative size of the two outgoing beams is still the ratio determined by $|\alpha/\beta|^2.$

But if you look at those incoming streamlines from the flow of probability current, the streamlines that end up giving you spin $+\hbar/2$ as the "x component of spin" are at the top part of the beam for one of those devices and at the bottom part of the beam for the other device.

These are two equally good devices that are merely calibrated differently. Neither device can be revealing a preexisting value of the "x component of spin" and there is no way around it.

And since textbooks like to act as if $|\psi|^2$ is what we measure, not the probability current I should point out that most detectors actually fire at a rate based on their cross section and the probability current density. And that it is these relative rates that we measure in the lab. All measurements are really interactions where things are changing. But that's just a plug for the idea that so called "probability current density" is not a completely unreal thing.

So we know that measurement is an interaction, and that the results depend on what you interact with as well as the thing being allegedly measured. And the thing being measured is changed to be forced into an eigenstate and there is no way around it.

So no. You aren't measuring some preexisting component of some vector. You are interacting with something to force you to evolve into an eigenstates and you do it in a way where doing it again doesn't split it at all, just deflects it. That "repeatability" is almost the only reason we call it a measurement.